# Angular not working under SSL via NgineX

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ssl, nginx

My default file in nginx https://github.com/NatuMyers/nginxSSL-setup/blob/master/default

I used that, then my node app doesn't allow Angular to work, it just serves the static index page, but the routing etc doesn't work.  When it was straight http it worked.

In my file with the node app I have app.js, node modules, and /public among other things.

in public I have angular packages, index.html, and partials.

When I call node app.js, it just serves index.html without the functionality. Here is a complete github of the set up minus the nginx content: https://github.com/NatuMyers/A.M.E.N.SQL-Stack

This is ubuntu, with Nginx on the digital ocean LAMP stack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are including angular.js with

```
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
```

When your browser is loading assets for a https website it will block http only scripts. So you should change your link to have no protocol, just `//` and the browser will insert whatever the rest of the page is loaded with.

```
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
```

Comment: It works. I know this is a stoic website, but I'm sooooo happy. thank you!